# What are the optimal parameters for docking a large ligand using Hex?

Tags: proteins, docking

I'm looking to dock a large ligand (~90kDa) to a receptor slightly larger receptor  (~125kDa) using Hex. If anyone is familiar with docking large structures, are there any recommended parameters for finding the best docking solution?

Parameters in particular:

- Number of Solutions
- N order of correlation for initial and final
  searches
- Receptor Range
- Ligand Range

Answer (score 1):

While I have no experience with this *specific* question you have, according to Feinstein & Brylinski ([2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4468813/)), a "fully automated procedure", i.e. a Perl script, can be used to optimize the box size itself, and it can be found [here](http://brylinski.cct.lsu.edu/content/docking-box-size).